# How to have different @Injectable for development and production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a rest-client object which in the production environment will point to a restful server and communicate with that. But in development mode, it will simply use browser's storage for ease of use.

I think the right way to do this is having two implementations of an interface, one for production and one for development. This way the rest of the application doesn't need to know about the production/development and can be tested just the same. All I need to do is to find a way to inject the right instance for each environment. And BTW, I prefer not to include the development version in the production code at all!

Does anyone know how to do this?

**[UPDATE]**

I've using Angular cli to kick off my project so I'm using Webpack (I think!). I prefer not to use an external mock server because I prefer to keep the test/development environment isolated from external dependencies. That way all I need to work on my frontend project is itself. Also, even though my question is focused on rest client, but of course this question can be generalized to any other singleton injectable.

I'm asking this question because in other DI frameworks that I worked with (namely Spring) doing so is part of the framework. So I was expecting to see the same here as well.

At this point, I know I can leverage the `environment.production` to check and see if it's in production mode or not. But first of all, this is a runtime variable but I think I'm looking for a compile-time one (I'm not sure though). Also, even though we have that variable but the following code leads to a compile error:

```
if (environment.production) {
  import { RestClientService } from './rest-client.service';
}
else {
  import { MockRestClientService as RestClientService } from './mock-rest-client.service';
}

ERROR in ... Duplicate identifier 'RestClientService'.
ERROR in ... An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module.
```

Comment: What build tool do you use? (i.e. webpack, rollup or some such?) As far as i know TypeScript itself cannot be helpful in such case. you need to "replace" the include path to this file during build process.

Comment: Of course you can always just made it at runtime based on some configuration or some such but then you'll have two of those implementations in code and the app itself will use the right one.

Comment: Why not use `MockBackend` and intercept Http calls (https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-services-in-angular-2), just curious about your usecase ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [factory provider](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#usefactorythe-factory-provider) for this:

```
export function restClientFactory(http: HttpClient): RestClientService {
  if (environment.production) {
    return new RestClientService(http);
  } else {
    return new MockRestClientService();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: RestClientService, useFactory: restClientFactory, deps: [ HttpClient ] },
  ],
})
class AppModule {}
```

---

The approach with conditional `import` statements doesn't work, because static `import` statements are allowed only at the top level of the file. They can not be nested inside `if/else` statement. You can use dynamic [`import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) to overcome this, but this will also lead to both implementations being included in your bundle.

---

Unfortunately there is no technical possibility to do a compile-time configuration of the DI like in Spring.

The main problem with runtime check is that both implementations will be included in your production bundle. You can rely on [tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), which is part of the production build, to ensure that your mock client is not included in the production bundle.

Since `environment.production` variable never changes you can expect that one branch of the `if/else` is never reachable and therefore can be dropped from bundle by tree-shaking process. The problem is that tool doing tree-shaking can not understand it, because variable is not declared as a `const`, but as a property of an object.

If you add `export const production = true` to `environment.prod.ts` and `export const production = false` to `environment.ts` and use this variable in the `if/else` statement one of the branches should be successfully tree shaken from the production bundle.

Note that this approach relies on the implementation detail of the Angular CLI. Nevertheless I successfully used it in one of my project for more than a year now.